# compass with vertical device

Tags: android, android-sensors

I know that the android orientation sensor isn't actually a sensor but it calculates it with results from magnetic field sensor and acceleration sensor.
The orientation sensor gives me the azimuth value but only if the device is parallel to the floor.

I want to build a compass which works when I hold my android device vertically.

Because the magnetic field sensor and the acceleration sensor give me values from the x-,y- and z-axis, shouldn't it be possible to get an accurate value for a compass when holding the device vertically (top points to the sky). 
But if it is possible how can I achieve this?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/hoananguyen/dsensor

Comment: Thank you! Is there a documentation about the different TYPEs? @HoanNguyen

Comment: Look at the DSensor and DProcessedSensor classes. The TYPEs are documented there.